# How to create a generic class in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I was trying to create a Generic Calculator in Scala which can work on all Integer types.
When I am trying the following code it gives me an error

Error: "Type mismatch. Required: String, found: T"

```
class Calculator[T <: Integral[T]] {
  def add[T](a: T, b: T): T = a + a
}
```

Can someone please explain to me how come it was expecting String type?

Comment: What are all these "Integer types" ?

Answer (score 3):

To answer the specific question, the type of `a + b` is `String` because Scala has a default `+` that works on any object by converting both arguments to a `String` and concatenating them. But what this is saying is that there is no other method `+` on `a` that can be used.

The broader problem is that `Numeric` is not the base class of all numeric types, but rather a *typeclass* that defines numeric behaviour on a type `T`. So the class defintion should look like this:

```
class Calculator[T : Integral] {
```

This tells the compiler that you can't create an instance of `Calculator[T]` unless there is an implicit instance of `Integral[T]` visible to the compiler at the time.

So there is an instance of `Integral[T]` that has methods that operate on `T` to do the basic numeric operations (`plus`, `times`, `negate` etc.). The next question is, how do I get hold of this instance of `Integral[T]`? The answer to that is `implicitly`, which will return the typeclass value for a type as long as it is available (otherwise it is a compile time error).

So the expression `implicitly[Integral[T]]` will return an instance of `Integral[T]` for whatever type was used to create the `Calculator`. And that instance knows how to `plus` values of type `T`. Once you know this, you can write your `add` function:

```
class Calculator[T : Integral] {
  def add(a: T, b: T): T = implicitly[Integral[T]].plus(a, b)
}
```

[Also note that there is no type parameter on `add` because the type parameter is on the class, so it is not `def add[T](...)` but just `def add(...)`]

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you see

```
Error: "Type mismatch. Required: String, found: T"
```

is that by default Scala 2 defines the following implicit method in `Predef`

```
implicit final class any2stringadd[A](private val self: A) extends AnyVal {
  def +(other: String): String = String.valueOf(self) + other
}
```

(this would not compile in Scala 3). If you wanted to write single non-generic calculator class that would work for all integral types (whatever that means for you - Scala doesn't have inheritance hierarchy that would restrict types to just `Int`, `Byte`, `Long`). You would use your own `Integer` typeclass

```
class Calculator {
  def add[A: Integer](lhs: A, rhs: A): A = implicitly[Integer[A]].plus(lhs, rhs)
}
```

with a following definition

```
trait Integer[A] {
  def plus(lhs: A, rhs: A): A
}

object Integer {
  implicit val Int: Integer[Int] = new Integer[Int] {
    override def plus(lhs: Int, rhs: Int): Int = lhs + rhs
  }

  // note explicit toByte cast -> byte addition can overflow! 
  // (thus result type is Int and you might want to stick 
  // to the original type in your use case)
  implicit val Byte: Integer[Byte] = new Integer[Byte] {
    override def plus(lhs: Byte, rhs: Byte): Byte = (lhs + rhs).toByte
  }
}
```

To make it look a bit nicer, you might leverage extension methods.

```
class Calculator {
  import Integer._
  def add[A: Integer](lhs: A, rhs: A): A = lhs + rhs
}

object Integer {
  implicit class IntegerOps[A: Integer](lhs: A) {
    def +(rhs: A): A = implicitly[Integer[A]].plus(lhs, rhs)
  }
  // the rest of the object stays the same
}
```

and with Scala 3, you can write it even more concisely

```
class Calculator {
  def add[A: Integer](lhs: A, rhs: A): A = lhs + rhs
}

trait Integer[A]:
  extension(a: A) def +(b: A): A
given Integer[Int] with
  extension(a: Int) def +(b: Int): Int = a + b
given Integer[Byte] with
  extension(a: Byte) def +(b: Byte): Byte = (a + b).toByte
```

Edit: per @Tim suggestion you can use `Integral` type class that is predefined. I will still leave my answer as a reference in case you wanted to implement similar typeclass by yourself.

Comment: Why define your own typeclass when `Integral` already exists?

Comment: good point @Tim :)